# irregular shape pixels intensities

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, shapes

please i want to get the mean intensity of the gray region.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhG6T.jpg)

any help i ll be thankfull

i tried to get the pixels coordinates and the intensity with this code (here is just the part of calculations):

```
    xp = x_centre - R2cos40
    yp = y_centre - rayon2
    angle = math.atan((x_centre - xp)/(y_centre - yp))
    somme_intensite = 0
    compteur_pixels = 0

    for x in range(x_centre - R2sin40, x_centre + R2cos40):
        for y in range(y_centre - rayon2, y_centre - R1sin40):
            if (x <= rayon2 * math.sin(angle) and \
                y < rayon1 and\
                    y > R1sin40 and\
                        angle < 315 and \
                            angle >= 255):
                somme_intensite += image.getpixel((x, y))
                compteur_pixels += 1
                xp += 1
                yp += 1
            else:
                xp += 1
                yp += 1
                
    intensite_moyenne = somme_intensite / compteur_pixels
    intensite_pourcentage = (intensite_moyenne / 255) * 100
```

Comment: I see 3 grey regions, not one. Also, they all seem to be solid, continuous-tone grey so you can just take any pixel in the area and you'll get the mean intensity because they are all the same.

Comment: the red line and the green one are just to mention some dimensions, so here i m talking about one gray area. if you dont mine please show me how to take all pixels in this area. i m beginner in python.